# FIltering similar points based on a criteria

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse, lubridate

I have include my example data set below. In the data set, I have multiple points for each `ID` during `hour` within a given day and there are some days with our a single point during each `hour` in a given day.

I would like to identify the points that have multiple points during each hour within a given day. For example, for `ID` "A" I have multiple points for `hour` 0 with `date` `2010-12-26`. Another criteria is that the `x` and `y` coordinates of these points should be different from one another (e.g., using the example for `hour` 2; the `x` and `y` coordinates of the first point should be different from the second point).

Here is the repeated point, the `x` and `y` should be different the two points, but I'm not sure how to change that up.

[image]

I would like to be able to identify and filter out these kinds of points from the data set.

Is there a good method to do this?

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy_hms("26-12-2010 00:00:00"), dmy_hms("31-12-2010 24:00:00"), by = "2 hours"), 100)
ID <- rep(c("A","B"), 100)
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID,
                 hour = hour(date))
```

Comment: Actually don't you only have one single point for ID "A" for hour 2 with date 2010-12-26? ... And also I don't see any hour with a value of 3 in `df`

Comment: Hey @John Huang, even after the edit, I still see only one point for ID "A" for hour 0 and date 2010-12-26, could you please filter the `df` and show which 2 rows satisfy these conditions as I can only see one row: `df %>% filter(ID == "A", date == as.Date("2010-12-26 00:00:00"))
        date        x        y ID hour
1 2010-12-26 79563.69 822815.3  A    0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Improved the code a bit to be more robust wrt to making sure all `x` and `y` coordinates are different even in larger groups.

So, I changed the code to generate `df` a bit in order to have these conditions actually appear in the data frame. My approach was then to group by `ID` and `date` (since that already contains the hour) and then check if all `x` and `y` coordinates are different within the group.
Here's the code and the result:

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy_hms("26-12-2010 00:00:00"), dmy_hms("31-12-2010 24:00:00"), by = "2 hours"), 100)
ID <- rep(c(rep("A", 25), rep("B", 25)), 2)
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID,
                 hour = hour(date))

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(date, ID) %>% 
  mutate(obs_per_hour_ID = n(),
         n_distinct_x = n_distinct(x),
         n_distinct_y = n_distinct(y),
         all_true = all(n_distinct_x == obs_per_hour_ID, 
                        n_distinct_y == obs_per_hour_ID,
                        obs_per_hour_ID > 1))

result <-  df %>% 
  filter(all_true) %>% 
  select(-contains("distinct"), -all_true, -obs_per_hour_ID)
result
#> # A tibble: 8 × 5
#> # Groups:   date, ID [4]
#>   date                     x       y ID     hour
#>   <dttm>               <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <int>
#> 1 2010-12-26 00:00:00 68249. 839183. A         0
#> 2 2010-12-26 02:00:00 67722. 881265. A         2
#> 3 2010-12-28 02:00:00 78020. 807422. B         2
#> 4 2010-12-28 04:00:00 72368. 873905. B         4
#> 5 2010-12-26 00:00:00 68788. 897331. A         0
#> 6 2010-12-26 02:00:00 67106. 804228. A         2
#> 7 2010-12-28 02:00:00 61158. 848782. B         2
#> 8 2010-12-28 04:00:00 65634. 889615. B         4
```

Created on 2022-02-02 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)